# Ender 3 v2 Pro issue where nozzle has nearly fallen off

Tags: creality-ender-3, nozzle, creality

So, I was 3D printing a shark and a portal toy to sell for my company [CCChoice](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1dEimYL2yq9XMLXeGYUrRHbM-WuOdolGOpMHGh6QdBHQ/edit?pli=1&pli=1&pli=1&no_redirect=true) overnight. I woke up in the morning to find the nozzle only hanging on by that one wire in the black mesh casing (images below). Every other place it was supposed to be attached it was detached from. The print didn't go too well either (image below). I don't know what attaches to what and where and am really confused. My backup printer is also out with a heating issue so I really have a problem. So, what caused this and how can I fix it, preferably without spending a bunch of money or taking a long time?

NOTE: I have an Ender 3 v2 Pro and use Ultimaker Cura with Polymaker's PLA 1 kg Orange filament and an 0.04 mm nozzle

[image: Photo of the hotend assembly fallen off of the X carriage]

[image: 3D printed model turned into 'spaghetti']

Comment: In your first photo, you can see the heated insert still attached to the X carriage. Somehow, from vibration or some other means, it has disconnected itself from the hotend assembly. How old is this printer? still under warranty?

Comment: Its 1 year old and I dont know @agarza

Comment: This is definitely NOT about filament itself and not about the slicer, so don't tag them if not strictly related

Comment: That's not the nozzle that's falling off, but the hotend shroud/fan bracket.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

So, I eventually managed to fix this, **but it only works for a few hours before the problem repeats. A full solution is welcome**. Here is an image below of a closeup

[image: Closeup photo of the points that attached the hotend assembly to the X carriage]

See that bottom black circle with 2 red circles inside of it? If you connect the 2 red circles then it will attach itself and the 2 red circles in the higher black circle will also latch together, reattaching the nozzle firmly. I still don’t know why this happened, but now it’s working.

[image: Photo of the hotend assembly reattached to the X carriage]

Comment: As noted in my comment to your question, the heated insert has detached itself from the hotend assembly. How long your fix will last is dependent on your repair.

Comment: I told you my repari @agarza

Comment: Yep this fix failed after a few hours of printing @agarza

Comment: Are the screws in the back actually screwed in?